# Stinkweed Imp + Rancor and a flying 3/3 blocker

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does [Stinkweed Imp](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stinkweed%20Imp) with [Rancor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rancor) get the extra trample damage if a 3/3 flyer blocks? Is Stinkweed's text is the same as an actual deathtouch?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

If a creature has been dealt damage by a source with deathtouch since the last time state-based actions were checked, that creature is destroyed. The damage itself leads to the destruction.

But that's not the case for [Stinkweed Imp](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stinkweed%20Imp). Its damage does not leads to the destruction, a triggered ability eventually does. It must assign damage normally, so it must assign all three of its damage to the flyer.

Here's the key difference: One can respond to Stinkweed's Imp's ability. It can even be [countered](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=46558).